# Allow switching the site before executing a query

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

Currently, if you open a Data Explorer query, you can't switch the site until you actually execute the query, because the site list is hidden. Please change this.

As it is, you either have to execute it and wait for SEDE to show you results you don't care about, or manually change the site name in the URL.

It also doesn't help that Stack Overflow is the default, because that site is gigantic compared to any other site in the network. Queries that work just fine on other sites time out because of that fact, and in that case, the site icons aren't even shown.

(Of course, those queries might not have a sensible limit and/or be horribly inefficient, but that's beside the point.)

Comment: Yeah, this definitely makes sense for the static view (and this might actually be a regression, whoops). I'll take a look at this later today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've now [pushed out an update](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=9ee5fb9bc90088e4a12cb547069209fc134bf860) for waffles to review and deploy, which will cause the bar to be displayed instantly for static queries (the ones without the editor) even if they haven't been run.

There's still an outstanding bug related to those site-switching links, but hopefully I can clobber that one later before anyone notices what it is.