# Always show the other-site-button-bar on the Data Explorer, even before executing query

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Allow switching the site before executing a query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123785/allow-switching-the-site-before-executing-a-query)

Today I ran across [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/59684/top-tags-by-closed-question-ratio) on the Data Explorer for Server Fault.

I wanted to execute it for Stack Overflow, but didn't see any easy way to do this, so I copied & pasted pasted it instead...

#### Later...

After I executed the query, a magical link-bar appeared for all of the Stack Exchange sites:

[image: site-selector bar]

Wouldn't it be a better user experience to show that bar *before* you execute a query?

Comment: Its CSS name is the `site-selector`, but I'm not sure if I like that any better than `dataexplorer-other-site-button-bar` :-)

Comment: Yes, sorry, this was on my to-do list...will (actually) get to it tonight.